# Count values that matches values with other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

SQL - Count number of columns that are having matching values then add count to the additional column.

Assuming I have a temp table with this value

| id | prod_name | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | attr4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test name | brand | bottle | size | 12x |

then I will need to compare it to product table having values of column by column:

| id | prod_name | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | attr4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | test name | brand | bottle | size | 12x |
| 4 | some name | brand | satchet | size | 1x |
| 5 | sample | brand | bottle | size | 23x |

expected result should be:

| id | prod_name | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | attr4 | CNT_Match_cols |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | test name | brand | bottle | size | 12x | 4 |
| 4 | some name | brand | satchet | size | 1x | 2 |
| 5 | sample | brand | bottle | size | 23x | 3 |

*CNT_Match_cols column is get of how many attr(X) columns that are having same values.

Comment: Does the expected result really match the sample table data?

Comment: What is your question here then? You've just dumped some requirements and some data. What is the problem you are having achieving your goal? What are you attempts? Why aren't they working?

Comment: What has this do with stored procedures? Seems you just want a query?

Comment: @jarlh yes it should be match with sample data

Answer (score 1):

You can cross join your tables and then count the attribute matches:

```sql
select prod.id, prod.prod_name, prod.attr1, prod.attr2, prod.attr3, prod.attr4
,   case when temp.attr1 = prod.attr1 then 1 else 0 end
    + case when temp.attr2 = prod.attr2 then 1 else 0 end
    + case when temp.attr3 = prod.attr3 then 1 else 0 end
    + case when temp.attr4 = prod.attr4 then 1 else 0 end as matched
from (
    VALUES  (1, N'test name', N'brand', N'bottle', N'size', N'12x')
) temp (id,prod_name,attr1,attr2,attr3,attr4)
cross join (
    VALUES  (3, N'test name', N'brand', N'bottle', N'size', N'12x')
    ,   (4, N'some name', N'brand', N'satchet', N'size', N'1x')
    ,   (5, N'sample', N'brand', N'bottle', N'size', N'23x')
) prod (id,prod_name,attr1,attr2,attr3,attr4)
```